# C#: Char to string

Tags: c#

Why when I enter an input on each line = "a" "b" "c", I don't get an output "abc" but "294"? I get it that they get the number of each letter from the ascii table, but can someone explain me what to do to get "abc"?

```
using System;

namespace CharsToString
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            char firstInput = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            char secondInput = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            char thirdInput = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine(firstInput + secondInput + thirdInput);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A `char` is a integral type, so you cant concatenate it, you are just _adding_ the values. You can use `StringBuilder` to construct a string

Comment: use StringBuilder to accumulate the characters into a string

Comment: @pm that will not work either unless you convert to string or do it in three steps.

Comment: If you just want to grab the first key that the user presses, you might want to take a look at the [`Console.ReadKey()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readkey?view=netframework-4.7.2) method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

char is a integral type, you are adding values you need to call `ToString` on each

```
Console.WriteLine(firstInput.ToString() + secondInput.ToString() + thirdInput.ToString());
```

Alternatively you could use a string builder, but given the example it seems like a premature optimization

Comment: The last two `.ToString()` can be implicit (because an overload `operator +(string, object)` exists), so: `Console.WriteLine(firstInput.ToString() + secondInput + thirdInput);` Another option is: `Console.WriteLine($"{firstInput}{secondInput}{thirdInput}");`

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen, I figured it would be better to be explicit to not confuse the op, but you have a good point this can be simplified

Comment: Some people even do `Console.WriteLine("" + firstInput + secondInput + thirdInput);`